# how to use position:absolute with scrolling

Tags: html, css

I've got the following div with the CSS for it in my HTML. I've fixed the div to the bottom of my page. I've designed my html content to be responsive and rearrange when the browser size gets small.

```
<div id="button-section">
 <!-- Section for function buttons -->
  <div id="function-buttons">
     <div class="fn-button">
     <!-- Function button -->
       <span>My Current Checks</span>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>



#button-section{
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
background-color: rgb(229, 229, 255);
min-width:1000px;
}

#function-buttons{
width: 70%;
height: 100%;
float:left;
min-width: 870px;
}
```

when I reduce the size of the browser, it only generates the horizontle scroll bar to show the fluid content! so the fixed content is half shown in the browser! I've displayed the scenario in the following image. How can I get the browser to accept the fixed content and show the exact amount with the scroll bar.

I tried putting it on relative mode but it doesn't work!

[image: without scrolling]

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that `position: fixed` is bad practice because on various devices it can break your layout, overlapping and such.

Comment: how can I then set the element fixed to the bottom of the browser!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I totally understand what the issue is — perhaps the scrollbar is the issue?  If that's the case then you might want to reduce the min-width value to something significantly less than 1000px.  By setting min-width, you're declaring that this section should be no less than x.  And in this case, x = 1000px.  That's why you're getting a scrollbar.

You need to remove that min-width value for starters.  Beyond that you'll have to evaluate your options for determining the width of the browser, perhaps using jQuery something along the lines of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var windowWidth = $(document).width();
    $('#button-section').css('min-width', windowWidth+'px');
});
</script>
```

Comment: this does not work! what happens here is that, even the scroll bar scrolls through the content, it does not scroll through the function buttons. the func button section sticks where it is, but does not scroll! if you can see in the images, it shows that the function buttons stay where they are but the other elements scroll!

Comment: To really help you out, I'd need to see this on some publicly-accessible site.  Screenshots do very little good to determine what exactly is wrong and why things are behaving the way they are.  Additionally, your question could use a little clarification — like what your expected behavior is, exactly what is wrong with it, and explanations about your screenshots.  There are elements in those images that I'm not sure what they are and how they pertain to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, position "Fixed" or "Absolute" does not work with scroll. Once you make it Fixed or Absolute, the child is no longer confined to its parent relativity and is removed out of the parent flow because of the fixed position. Make the position:relative to the parent if you want it to scroll.

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: how can I fix the element to the bottom of the page with it being relative! can you please explain if there is any method!

Comment: You can do some tricks. Fix it to the bottom but when someone is trying to re-size window or scroll, detect it through javascript and make it relative. Something like that you can try.